# has_many :through but only sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have an app that contains many `Users` where each  `User` has many `Questions`

**Why I need to do this**

Now, we want the ability to scoop up some `Messages` into `Questions`. This is complicated because not all `Messages` will belong to a `Question`. Here is an example:

```
- = Not (really) a question
x = Belongs to question x
y = Belongs to question y

[-] Hey
[-] Hey, what's up?
[x] Not much. Hey, what's a good movie to see tonight?
[x] How about Star Wars?
[x] Great idea! Thanks.
[-] You bet.
[-] Star wars is awesome.
[-] Yeah it is.
[-] Hey I have another question
[-] Shoot
[y] Where should I go on vacation this summer?
[y] Go to France, it's beautiful.
[y] Yeah, I'll go to France.
[-] Any other questions?
[-] No, but thanks for your help.
```

**What needs to happen**

As an end result, I would want to see a stream of messages and mark the ones that are part of a question, as above. So it would be nice to do something like

```
@messages.each do |message|
  if not message.question.blank?
    ...
```

And I would like to mark the category (attribute of `Question`) of the question.

```
@message.question.update(category: 3)
```

I'd also like to view a single question and apply categories to it so I can pull up something like this:

```
p = @question.category
ul
  @question.messages.each do |message|
    li = message.content
```

My concern is that messages won't always be related to a question at all. So **how should I structure my data?**

**Update**

One more thing I forgot to mention is that the data should be output ultimately as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is create some methods in `Message` to handle the whole `if question.present?` check, eg.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question

  def category
    question.try(:category) || "-"
  end

  # ...
end
```

So then you could do something like this in your view:

```
@messages.each do |m|
  = "[#{m.category}] #{m.text}"
```

Comment: Does the try account for the fact that message may not have a question parent?

Comment: Yes, [see the docs for it here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

Comment: Thanks, so would a simple `has_many :messages` work as an association for the `Question` object?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have `question_id` field in your `messages` table then that will work fine.